# How do I sort a subquery in a computed column that generates a json array and limit to the top 5 results?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I sort the json_agg column statement below by the rssi column and limit the json array produced to the top 5 rows?

```
select
     id,
     name,
     group_id,
     last_seen_at,
     (select count(distinct iot_device_id) from public.sensor s where s.power_bridge_id=pb.id) as iot_devices_count,
     (select json_agg(json_build_object('iot_device_id', s.iot_device_id, 'name', s."name", 'rssi', s."rssi")) from sensor s where s.power_bridge_id=pb.id) as iot_devices
from public.power_bridge pb where group_id=$1
order by lower(name)
```

I don't know what to try to sort the json array that is produced in the sub column.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some data sample and the exact expected result

Answer (score 0):

Use `Order by rssi` and `limit 5` before the rows are aggregated :

```
select json_agg(obj) as iot_devices
from (
  select json_build_object('iot_device_id', s.iot_device_id, 'name', s."name", 'rssi', s."rssi") as obj 
  from sensor s 
  where s.power_bridge_id=pb.id
  order by s.rssi 
  limit 5
) as s
```